# C compile error

Tags: c

What does the following error mean when compiling.

```
Tilemap.h:21: error: conflicting types for ‘ThreeDWorld’
Tilemap.h:21: error: previous declaration of ‘ThreeDWorld’ was here
Tilemap.h:29: error: conflicting types for ‘CGPoint’
Tilemap.h:29: error: previous declaration of ‘CGPoint’ was here
Tilemap.h:31: error: conflicting types for ‘tileForCoordinates’
Tilemap.h:31: error: previous declaration of ‘tileForCoordinates’ was here
```

Why is it giving an error for what was there?My source file has one instance of it as such

```
typedef struct
{
int xPosition;
int yPosition;
} 
CGPoint;
```

Comment: Are you incidentally working with Obj-C and XCODE ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you including the header file from more than one place? Use a guard in the header file, if so.

For example, in Tilemap.h:

```
 #ifndef TILEMAP_H
 #define TILEMAP_H

 // header file contents

 #endif /* TILEMAP_H */
```

Comment: Some compilers support  #pragma once.

Answer (score 2):

Stick some inclusion guards on your headers.

Your type definition is appearing more than once in your compilation unit.

Answer (score 2):

You included the header file twice.

In my own code, I wrapped all header files with

```
#ifndef HEADER_FILE_NAME
#define HEADER_FILE_NAME

#endif
```

to avoid such errors.